# Number of dopaminergic neurons in VTA

Tags: cell-biology, neuroscience, histology, dopamine, mouse

Do you know an authoritative source for the approximate number of dopaminergc cells in the ventral tegmental area (VTA)?
Ideally I would like to know this for mice, rats, as well as humans, but one species alone would be a nice start. I have looked for this via google scholar and pubmed, but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating the information from @WYSIWYG's excellent answer, it appears the dopaminergic neuron count lies at:

- 4k for mice - [Triarhou, 1988](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF00248351.pdf)
- 10k for rats - [German and Manaye, 1993](https://doi.org/10.1002/cne.903310302)
- 250k-440k for humans - [Rice et al, 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4504823/)

Answer (score 2):

Approximately, 250000-440000 neurons in Humans ([Rice et al., 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4504823/)).

> The substantia nigra/ventral tegmental area (SN/VTA) complex is a
>   heterogeneous collection of dopaminergic cell groups that extends from
>   diencephalic to mesencephalic territories in many vertebrates,
>   including rodents, non-human primates, and humans (Puelles and Verney
>   1998; see as reviews Smits et al. 2006; Smidt and Burbach 2007; Smits
>   et al. 2013). The SN/VTA contains the largest number of dopaminergic
>   neurons in the brain (see as reviews van Domburg and ten Donkelaar
>   1991; Haber and Fudge 1997; Nieuwenhuys et al. 2008), with average
>   estimates ranging in most studies from **approximately 250,000 –
>   440,000 dopaminergic neurons** within the complex (Bogerts et al.
>   1983; Hirsch et al. 1988; van Domburg and ten Donkelaar 1991; Damier
>   et al. 1999a; Kubis et al. 2000).

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas about the other species?

Comment: @TheChymera no idea. I'm also relying on Google scholar and pubmed. I have no expertise in this field.